# Python Kivy and adding local photos to Carousel

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, carousel, kivy-language

Please forgive me I am in my infancy learning Python and started using Kivy not too long ago.

I am simply trying to add photos from my "carousel/" directory in my project to be each photo that comes up in the carousel app one by one when it loads.

The code runs fine, and I am even able to load Async photos with the link to the photo, but for whatever reason when I try to load photos from my "carousel" folder they don't show up.

I know that these photos return otherwise because I used the "Image" call and it worked, I also looked all over and there were other solutions but I could not make the connection between their solution and what it is I need.

Here is the code and a picture below, like I said the code builds and runs fine but the pictures won't show up. Thank you in advance!

```
[from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.core.image import Image
from kivy.factory import Factory


class CarouselApp(App):

    def build(self):

        carousel = Carousel(direction='right')

        for i in range(0,2):
            src = "carousel/%s.jpg" % str(i)
            image = Factory.AsyncImage(source=src, allow_stretch=True)
            carousel.add_widget(image)
        return carousel

CarouselApp().run()][1]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/igyeq.png

Comment: Instead of writing "solved" in the question title, you can accept the most helpful answer, this gives some thank-you reputation points to the answerer and yourself, then you can remove "SOLVED!!" :)

Comment: @Jonathan, ...see the checkbox by each answer -- selecting one of them is how you mark your question solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to store all your pictures in a folder called carousel, and you can remove the Factory.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage


class CarouselApp(App):

    def build(self):

        carousel = Carousel(direction='right')

        for i in range(0, 6):
            src = "carousel/%s.png" % str(i)
            image = AsyncImage(source=src, allow_stretch=True)
            carousel.add_widget(image)
        return carousel


CarouselApp().run()
```

### Output

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to load `'carousel/0.jpg'` and `'carousel/1.jpg'` instead of `'carousel_images/00.jpg'` and `'carousel_images/01.jpg'`, Try this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.core.image import Image
from kivy.factory import Factory


class CarouselApp(App):

    def build(self):

        carousel = Carousel(direction='right')

        for i in range(0,2):
            src = "carousel_images/0{}.jpg".format(str(i))
            image = Factory.AsyncImage(source=src, allow_stretch=True)
            carousel.add_widget(image)
        return carousel

CarouselApp().run()
```

Comment: Oops, I apologize I changed the images to .jpg because I thought that the problem was the .png file type.

I loaded this code and it still doesn't show the images, this is similar to the code I had before.

Comment: @Jonathan this code works perfectly for me, the problem is your `carousel`  folder location I don't see it in your project structure

Comment: Hey sorry if I don't respond to all accounts I'm still figuring out how StackOverflow operates with comments haha.

ikolim and SP SP this totally works thank you for saving me from the headache! I spent hours last night.

Comment: @Jonathan you are welcome, but don't add solved in the title of your question you have just to choose one answer by clicking the right icone at the left corner of the right answer